# On the norm of powers of an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Can someone provide me an example of some linear bounded operator on a Banach space $X$, $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$, such that $\sup_k ||T^{2k+1}||<\infty$ and such that $sup_k||T^{2k}||=\infty$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\|T^{2k+1}\|\le M$ for all $k$, then $\|T^{2k+2}\|\le\|T\|\|T^{2k+1}\|
\le M\|T\|$, so that the sequence $(\|T^{2k}\|)$ is bounded...